# Background opacity change based on conditional statement not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, conditional-statements

I'm building a calorie calculator. It has a diet filter in it. If a diet is selected, the items that do not fit the diet become greyed out and unclickable. This works on desktop, however, on mobile it does not achieve the desired effect. What can be wrong?

Here it is live:

http://www.padthai.decorolux.com/Calorie/

Here's a pen also:

https://codepen.io/Pbalazs89/full/GxYdOY

```
    //  Filters + Description text setup

$(document).on('click', '.diet-filter-button', function () {
     var map = {
        vegan: {
            attr: 'vegan',
            desc: 'veganDescription'
        },
        vegeterian: {
            attr: 'vegetarian',
            desc: 'vegetarianDescription'
        },
        gluten: {
            attr: 'glutenfree',
            desc: 'glutenFreeDescription'
        },
        lactose: {
            attr: 'lactoseFree',
            desc: 'lactoseFreeDescription'
        },
        addedSugar: {
            attr: 'noAddedSugar',
            desc: 'noAddedSugarDescription'
        }
    },
    diet = $(this).data('diet'),
    filtered = $(this).hasClass("filtered");

    if (filtered) {
        $(this).removeClass("filtered");
        $(".ingredient:not([" + map[diet]['attr'] + "])").fadeTo(1000, 1).css("pointer-events", "auto");
        $("#" + map[diet]['desc']).css("opacity", "0");
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("filtered");
        $(".ingredient:not([" + map[diet]['attr'] + "]").fadeTo(1000, 0.5).css("pointer-events", "none");
        $("#" + map[diet]['desc']).css("opacity", "1");
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="contenttable">
          <div class="dropdown">
                  <div class="dropdownmenu">
                    <button class="dropbtn main">Diet or Allergen Filter <i class="fa fa-sort-up" style="line-height:0px; margin-left: 5px;"></i></button></div>

                   <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a id="veganDiet" class="dropbtn2 diet-filter-button" data-diet="vegan"> Vegan</a>
    <a id="vegetarianDietButton" class="dropbtn2 diet-filter-button" data-diet="vegeterian"> Vegetarian</a>
    <a id="noGlutenButton" class="dropbtn2 diet-filter-button" data-diet="gluten"> Gluten-Free</a>
    <a id="noLactoseButton" class="dropbtn2 diet-filter-button" data-diet="lactose"> Lactose-Free</a>
    <a id="noAddedSugarButton" class="dropbtn2 diet-filter-button" data-diet="addedSugar"> No Added Sugar</a>
</div>
              </div> 

            <div class="maindish">




<div id="VeganNoBaseSauce"></div>


                <!-- BASES -->
                <div><img class="headingimage" src="http://www.padthai.decorolux.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/ikonok-06.png"></div>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="15%">Bases</th>
                        <th width="20%"></th>
                        <th width="15%" style="font-weight:normal">Calories</th>
                        <th width="15%" style="font-weight:normal">Carbs</th>
                        <th width="15%" style="font-weight:normal">Fat</th>
                        <th width="15%" style="font-weight:normal">Protein</th>
                        <th width="5%" style="font-weight:normal">Add</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr vegetarian vegan lactosefree glutenfree soyfree sugarfree noaddedsugar>
                        <td><img src='http://www.padthai.decorolux.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/base_toppings_extra.png'></td>
                        <td>Rice Noodle</td>
                        <td>517.2</td>
                        <td>76.1</td>
                        <td>14.4</td>
                        <td>20.8</td>
                        <td class="ingredients" data-calories="517.2" data-carbs="76.1" data-fat="14.4" data-proteins="20.8"><i class="fa fa-plus" style="font-size:20px;"></i></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="ingredient" vegetarian lactosefree soyfree sugarfree noaddedsugar>
                        <td><img src='http://www.padthai.decorolux.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/base_toppings_extra2.png'></td>
                        <td>Egg Noodle</td>
                        <td>510.5</td>
                        <td>66.1</td>
                        <td>14.1</td>
                        <td>29.8</td>
                        <td class="ingredients" data-calories="510.5" data-carbs="66.1" data-fat="14.1" data-proteins="29.8"><i class="fa fa-plus" style="font-size:20px;"></i></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="ingredient" vegetarian vegan lactosefree glutenfree soyfree sugarfree noaddedsugar>
                        <td><img src='http://www.padthai.decorolux.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/base_toppings_extra3.png'></td>
                        <td>Vermicelli</td>
                        <td>506.9</td>
                        <td>76.9</td>
                        <td>14.1</td>
                        <td>18.1</td>
                        <td class="ingredients" data-calories="506.9" data-carbs="76.9" data-fat="14.1" data-proteins="18.1" ><i class="fa fa-plus" style="font-size:20px;"></i></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="ingredient" vegetarian vegan lactosefree soyfree sugarfree noaddedsugar>
                        <td><img src='http://www.padthai.decorolux.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/base_toppings_extra4.png'></td>
                        <td>Whole Grain Noodle</td>
                        <td>476.6</td>
                        <td>53.8</td>
                        <td>16.6</td>
                        <td>28.0</td>
                        <td class="ingredients" data-calories="476.6" data-carbs="53.8" data-fat="16.6" data-proteins="28" ><i class="fa fa-plus" style="font-size:20px;"></i></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="ingredient" vegetarian vegan  glutenfree soyfree sugarfree noaddedsugar>
                        <td><img src='http://www.padthai.decorolux.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/base_toppings_extra5.png'></td>
                        <td>White Rice</td>
                        <td>514.8</td>
                        <td>72.4</td>
                        <td>14.8</td>
                        <td>23.0</td>
                        <td class="ingredients" data-calories="514.8" data-carbs="72.4" data-fat="14.8" data-proteins="23" ><i class="fa fa-plus" style="font-size:20px;"></i></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="ingredient" vegetarian vegan lactosefree glutenfree soyfree sugarfree noaddedsugar>
                        <td><img src='http://www.padthai.decorolux.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/base_toppings_extra6.png'></td>
                        <td>Brown Rice</td>
                        <td>516.0</td>
                        <td>70.1</td>
                        <td>16.0</td>
                        <td>22.9</td>
                        <td class="ingredients" data-calories="516" data-carbs="70.1" data-fat="16" data-proteins="22.9" ><i class="fa fa-plus" style="font-size:20px;"></i></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="ingredient" vegetarian vegan lactosefree glutenfree soyfree sugarfree noaddedsugar>
                        <td><img src='http://www.padthai.decorolux.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/base_toppings_extra7.png'></td>
                        <td>Vegetable Base</td>
                        <td>106.6</td>
                        <td>14.2</td>
                        <td>1.8</td>
                        <td>8.4</td>
                        <td class="ingredients" data-calories="106.6" data-carbs="14.2" data-fat="1.8" data-proteins="8.4" ><i class="fa fa-plus" style="font-size:20px;"></i></td>
                    </tr>



                </table>
```

*BONUS Question:

When viewing from iphone 6 plus (425px width) the ''Diet or Allergen Filter'' button appears way to huge. I tried to set up a @media max-width 440px to configure it, but it seems to have no effect. If I view it from Chrome on my desktop the @media query works fine, but not on mobile. All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is only in CSS and you give an "!important" in some properties.
And every time check design removes all history in your browser and mobile or use the private browser.